# facebook graph api and file_get_contents = 403

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a simple script to fetch user profile data from an id.

For example

```
$link = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/zuck'));
echo $link_>name;
```

The problem is that it's seems like facebook is limiting these kind of requests. Sometimes it's working, but sometimes I'm getting the following error :

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://graph.facebook.com/zuck)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I just started seeing this exact issue over this past weekend (10/26/2013-10/27/2013)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `curl` instead of `file_get_contents` and use [curl_error](https://www.php.net/curl_error) to see why it returns 403. There's a request limit that you might reach and that might be the cause why it gives you 403.